# Explicit array property versus a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to refactor a simple function:

```
// arr - array of objects with functions
function eventNotify(arr, event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var a = arr[i];
        if (typeof a[event] === 'function') {
            a[event]();
        }
    }
}
```

into this one:

```
function eventNotify(arr, event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var a = arr[i][event];
        if (typeof a === 'function') {
            a();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm stuck trying to comprehend how such change manages to break all my tests.

How is it possible that the second implementation is functionally different from the first one?

I even tried to split the use of indexes, thinking that maybe it is treated as a 3D array:

```
var a = arr[i];
a = a[event];
```

But no, this makes no difference.

Please somebody point out what on earth am I changing in the logic of the algorithm there! I'm wracking my brain over this one now.

---

I'm testing it under Node.js 10.9

Comment: You're breaking the object relationship and therefore `this` won't be set when the function is called.

Comment: @Pointy So `this` on explicit array addressing works, as opposed to just a variable. I knew the secret was somewhere in the intensity of my head-banging on the table... But this one is quite a revelation. If you want to make it into an answer, I will accept it ;)

Comment: In the first example the function context (`this` value) is `arr[i]`. In the second, its the global object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy)

My mistake was in not being able to see that syntax `a[event]()` obscures the fact that it passes in `this` context set to object `a`, while simple `a()` does not, hence the result discrepancy.

Comment: If you did want to do just -> `a()`, you could use bind. `var a = arr[i][event].bind(arr[i])`

Comment: @Keith I did this as part of some performance optimization, by replacing some `forEach` loops that work awfully slower than `for` inside old browsers, like IE9/10. And your solution would make it even slower than that, as you are calling a function that creates and returns another function that swaps calling context.

Comment: Using bind can actually increase performance, it of course depends how you use it.   Using bind inside a loop would not be ideal though.